# How to monitor multiple elasticsearch clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

`marvel` just can monitor one cluster at one time,but i have a lot of clusters.Is there some better way to monitor multiple clusters on one big page?

Comment: The Marvel app in Kibana 4.3 allows you to monitor multiple clusters.

Comment: @Val,Setting up a separate monitoring cluster,and all clusters write data to the monitoring cluster?

Comment: @zmy where you able to find an answer to your question? Had a similar question.